# Can I reach docker started services via internal url?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running applications using docker containers. I run it with docker-compose. For example there is arangodb dependency:

```
  arangodb:
image: localartifactiory/arangodb:3.2.5
volumes_from:
  - arangodb_data
ports:
  - 8530:8529
environment:
  - ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
```

I can reach the service with `http://localhost:8530`, but I can't reach it using service name `http://arangodb:8530` or `http://arangodb:8529` in browser, still it looks like my application connects to this db by `http://arangodb:8529` address.

Can you please tell me if it is possible to reach my service using service-based-url from browser or is it internal docker address that can be reached only inside containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service name url is available due to the [embedded DNS server in user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/). This DNS server is only used to resolve DNS requests for containers that are part of the network.

Check [Query docker embedded dns from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729663/query-docker-embedded-dns-from-host) to see how to resolve DNS names using the embedded DNS server

Answer (score 0):

- To access service externally (from the browser) you need to use IP_ADDRESS of the host machine. Host machine means Windows/Ubuntu/ Mac, actual machine address.
- To access service internally from one container to another then you can use container name (e.g. http://arangodb:8529).

let me know if you need any further details.